# android layout is not showing proper on some resolutions

Tags: android, layout

My android layout with grid view is not showing properly on 480 x 854 pixels (~196 ppi pixel density) device.and please suggest me is there any method to work with layout creation at run time.

Comment: you should have look https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenSizeQualifier

Comment: You can use android:numColumns="auto_fit"

Comment: ok @Krutik that is also a way

Answer (score 1):

> Android categorizes device screens using two general properties: size
>   and density. You should expect that your app will be installed on
>   devices with screens that range in both size and density.

### [Create Different Layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

To optimize your user experience on different screen sizes, you should create a unique layout XML file for each screen size you want to support. Each layout should be saved into the appropriate resources directory .

More info you can visit official guideline

1. **[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)**

Comment: I am using  float px = dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT); to convert dp to px. It works fine on devices with dpi density but when it comes to devices in which density is measured into PPI it shows different output.

Comment: @N.Shah OKAY . Is there any problem for `DisplayMetrics` ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Answer (score 0):

@N.shah , For Gridview, You should make all view dynamic, So that all the cells come exactly on each and every device
How We can do this
Like we have 4 rows and 2 columns
All 4 rows should show on window
 1. Find out the device width and height
 2. Lets say height is X. Find out height of status bar i.e Y  and action bar Z
 3. Find out the exact height where we have to show our gridview i.e 
    X=X-(Y+Z)
 4. Divide the X by no. of rows you want to show to find out row height i.e R
   R=X/4( where 4 is no. of rows)
 5. Create an xml which you want to show in gridview

custom_gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/menu_grid_vertical_spacing"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4.5" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.9"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:padding="@dimen/menu_page_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4" />

        <com.slinfy.ikharelimiteduk.custom.CustomTextViewSegoeUISemiBold
            android:id="@+id/txt_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/app_menu_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_grid_vertical_spacing"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#2E3A60" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Make an adapter

GridViewAdapter

```
import com.slinfy.ikharelimiteduk.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint({ "ViewHolder", "InflateParams" })
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] mMenuNames;
    int[] mColors;
    Integer[] mMenuIcons;
    Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    float mGridSize;
    float mPadding;
    int noOfColums = 4;

    public GridViewAdapter(String[] menuNames, Context context, int[] colors, Integer[] menuIcons, float gridSize) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mMenuNames = menuNames;
        mMenuIcons = menuIcons;
        mColors = colors;
        mContext = context;
        mGridSize = gridSize;
        mPadding = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_grid_vertical_spacing);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMenuIcons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (arg1 == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gridview, null);
            holder.imgMenu = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_menu);
            holder.txtName = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            holder.layout = (RelativeLayout) arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            arg1.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtName.setText(mMenuNames[index]);
        holder.imgMenu.setImageResource(mMenuIcons[index]);
        holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(mColors[index]);
        holder.layout.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT,
                (int) ((mGridSize / noOfColums) - 5/* - (mPadding) - 6 */)));
        return arg1;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        ImageView imgMenu;
        RelativeLayout layout;
    }
}
```

Set the adapter in your main class

```
GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
grid.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(menuNames, getApplicationContext(), colors, menuIcons, gridSize));
```